# What ten-letter word means "having lots of time"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I came upon [this Yahoo! Answers question](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index;_ylt=AgFdSZpGw14qMFumtBMp62PCxQt.;_ylv=3?qid=20130908050150AA9YuQa), which asks:

> What 10 letter word means have lots of time?

The "best answer" (five stars!) was *plentiful*, a nine-letter word that doesn't really have anything to do with time.

So now I'm curious... anything?

Comment: Solving a crossword????

Comment: There's a crossword puzzle solver here where you can enter clues, word-lengths etc. http://www1.oneacross.com/

Comment: How about "lotsoftime"?

Comment: perhaps a little tongue-in-cheek but: *unemployed*

Answer (score 2):

*Leisureful*. It is likely to be absent from all but unabridged dictionaries because it is no longer used.

Answer (score 1):

Had to change my original answer.
 
<sub>I got it totally wrong.</sub>

***Enduringly***

meaning: *lasting lots of time* (not quite what you were looking for but it's an improvement)

Answer (score 1):

I think *[eternities](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eternities)*, “Plural form of eternity”, (where *[eternity](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eternity#Noun)* means an infinite time) might be the best choice for a noun, and *[commodious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/commodious#Adjective)*,  “Spacious and convenient; roomy and comfortable”, might serve as an adjective.  Also consider *[unabridged](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unabridged#Adjective)*,  “Not abridged, shortened, expurgated or condensed; complete”.  At a stretch, *[unseasoned](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unseasoned)* (without season) might work.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps @Jim 's answer was just as serious as jocular: I thought of *unoccupied* which is, in my opinion, quite similar to *unemployed*.